# SSL and Diffie-Hellman

Tags: sockets, encryption

So I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055083/how-can-i-encrypt-my-message-when-sending-to-the-server-can-some-1-add-in-the-c) and was surprised by the answer of Remus. Because I thought it was exactly the other way around.

So, as for my question. Why is a program using the diffie-hellman key exchange to settle on a shared key to encrypt/decrypt messages (generally) less secure than SSL?

Edit: I know SSL uses a digital certificate but as my program only communicates with itself (client-server) that doesn't matter anyway, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remus post mainly cautions against creating your own crypto protocols (because you probably will make some fatal mistake) and instead use the existing solution SSL.

You can write a secure network protocol using only Diffie-Hellman as asymmetric crypto together with some symmetric crypto. My favourite secure network protocol works like that. A program using DH isn't weaker than SSL per se, but a program where a non crypto expert designed the protocol most likely is.

But if you design your own protocol, you will need to learn a bit of crypto to do it correctly. You probably want expert review for your design and code as well, in case you made a mistake somewhere. But getting that review isn't easy unless your product is famous enough or you pay them.

The SSL handshake does two major things:

1. It uses the certificate to verify that the server is authorized to represent the domain you want to communicate with.

   In the most common case a Certificate Authority vouches that the owner of a certain keypair is the rightful owner of a certain domain (this takes the form of a certificate). This part is only as secure as the weakest recognized CA.

   If you only need to communicate only with a single server, you can hardcode the server's fingerprint cutting out the whole CA and PKI part. This approach is similar to the way you typically handle SSH fingerprints.
2. It generates a session key

Strong SSL suites use the certificate for authenticating the server and DH to generate the session key. Weaker suites use the certificate for both.

Naive DH based protocols will probably forget to authenticate the server, allowing an active attacker to MitM the connection. You need to authenticate the server somehow, even if it's simply by hardcoding the server's public key in your client.

Comment: To get things straight, what if a man-in-the-middle gets the certificate that is being send, why isn't that an issue?

Comment: Certificates is signed by well-known third-party - CA (Certification authority). Because hacker can't forge signature - he can't forge certificate

Comment: @BioCycle Because a certificate doesn't contain any secret information. A certificate is essentially a statement like "I, Verisign guarantee that the owner of public key X is may represent example.com -- signed Verisign". Now since your browser knows Verisign's public key(it's hardcoded) it can verify that statement and since it trusts the CA it now trusts X.

Comment: SSL uses the server certificate to prove that the server is who he says he is. This is to prevent MITM attacks. It is an *authentication* step, not an authorization step. *HTTPS* also uses it to verify that the server belongs to the domain you connected to. This is a mild authorization step.

Answer (score 2):

Remus isn't commenting on the pros and cons of a particular encryption algorithm.

He is instead commenting on the need to avoid writing your own crypto protocols. **I agree with him 100%**.

Writing encryption protocols is very difficult and fraught with peril. Any number of exceptionally subtle bugs can easily creep in and make your entire system insecure. Even experts often get things wrong and need to patch things at future dates.

It's also a sign of platform maturity that it's so easy with WCF other platform components to use the stock tools.

Answer (score 0):

SSL uses digital certificates to prevent Man-in-the-Middle attacks. If hacker can not only intercept, but modify messages, your DH-based encryption will fail because your programm will establish secret key with hacker, and hacker will establish secret key with server. You can use RSA keypair to establish secret keys - public key in client, private key in server. Because hacker don't know private key, he can't decrypt secret key.

Comment: Can you explain why digital certificates cannot be faked by a man-in-the-middle?

Comment: what you are describing is a PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) ... certificates alone won't prevent MITM attacks ... it may be clear to you that certificates can be validated if the signing CA is trustworthy and the CA certificate is known, but that is a PKI ... certificates alone can't do that unless you have some trust chain ... the most trivial form might be manual certificate pinning

Comment: regarding your edit about RSA ... this only works if you have a fool proof way to get your key to the client (like hardcoding it) ... if the key is meant to be exchanged, ALL asymetric crypto schemas are vulnerable against MITM, unless you have a working PKI and can secure the keys with certificates

Comment: Yes, that I meant - public key is hardcoded in client or signed with hardcoded key.

Comment: Using RSA to encrypt session keys is one method, but I think just using RSA to authenticate and ephemeral Diffie-Hellman (EDH) for session key generation is safer because it does not use the private key to encrypt but to sign.

Comment: @owlstead (EC)DHE is certainly preferable. But I don't think it's common yet. Most websites still use plain RSA suites. Gmail uses ECDHE but most other major websites don't.

Comment: Why is better and/or safer? Both solutions need secret key, and why don't encrypt shared secret with public key?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'll try and find some references for that, thanks (+1 by the way)

Comment: @Maxim If you use the server's long term public key (the one on the certificate) for key-exchange this implies that when your server gets compromised an attacker can decrypt all past communications. If you use ephemeral keys, i.e. a new key for each connection such a compromise will only allow impersonation and can be mitigated by revoking the certificate. This security property is called [Perfect forward secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy). ECDHE also allows higher security with good performance since ECC is better than RSA.

Comment: Certificates cannot be faked because the server is required by SSL to provide a digital signature signed with the private key. Only the certificate owner can do that. This is an authentication step. The application is then supposed to do an authorization step to determine whether that authenticated identity is the one he should be communicating with.